# boost spirit recursive parsing

Tags: c++, recursion, boost

I have read other topics about recursive parsing, but those solutions are not sufficient for me.

Let's have such a simple parser:

```
struct B;
typedef boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<B> > A;
struct B {
    B() {
        static int l = 0;
        cout << "B() " << ++l << endl;
    }
    A a1;
    A a2;
};
// fusion adapt structs ....

typedef std::string::iterator iter;
typedef rule<iter, B()> BRule;
typedef rule<iter, A()> ARule;

ARule a;
BRule b;
a %= b | int_;
b %= a >> lit(',') >> a;
std::string s("5,8,3,1");

iter be = s.begin();
iter en = s.end();

B u;
parse(be, en, b, u);
```

I want to parse something like 's' string: "5,1,3,9" - this should consist of B element which contains 2 B elements which contain just integers.

It causes - according to the site name - stack overflow.
When I add parenthises:

```
b %= '(' >> a >> lit(',') >> a >> ')';
std::string s("((5,8),(3,1))");
```

... everything works fine.

Is there any possibility to avoid parenthises and use parsers int this manner:

```
a %= b ....
b %= a ...
```

??
Not necessarily such a notation, but for parsing '3,4,5,6' instead of '((3,4),(5,6))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't do that.** 
A PEG parser will simply bounce back and forth between those two rules.

Why isn't your parser simply:

```
b %= int_ >> *(lit(',') >> int_);
```

Alternatively, you'll often see constructs of the form:

```
expression %= primary >> *(lit(',') >> primary);
primary    %= '(' >> expression >> ')' | int_;
```

You could also use a [list parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html) and write that as:

```
expression %= primary % lit(',');
primary    %= '(' >> expression >> ')' | int_;
```

Comment: Technically, Spirit is PEG

Answer (score 0):

Of course, better is

```
a %= b % ','
```

for comma-delimited numbers, but that was just a fake example to show the problem's essence.

As written, the solution is:

```
    a %= b ....
    b %= any_rule_that_consumes_input >> .... a ....
```